# 10.04 LTS SVN how quick are updates?

Tags: svn

I am new to Ubuntu LTS.  I am using the SVN server that comes with 10.04 it is 1.6.6.  The current version is 1.6.17. How quickly can I expect an update to the LTS applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the LTS will not get new versions of applications, but rather security patches and bugfixes to current package version - the version number will likely never change, however there could be new features backported, but not likely. Your best bet would be the [Subversion PPA](https://launchpad.net/~svn/+archive/ppa) but that only goes to 1.6.17.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

If you are wanting something newer than than, you will likely have to install from source unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Important security bugfix updates you can expect very quickly, but it will be on base of 1.6.6 (base vesrion for this release) with merged only security changes, so you will have package version like: `1.6.6dfsg-2ubuntu1.3`. See [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/subversion/subversion_1.6.6dfsg-2ubuntu1.3/changelog).

So, if you care about security, stick with normal package from normal repo. 
If you care about some new features, you need to:

1. compile it by your self (and take care about updates by your self!), or
2. install some PPA package without support, or
3. install package from newer ubuntu release

All of above are messy - do you really want it?